# mysqli_real_escape_string Catchable fatal error error

Tags: php, sql-injection

i want to insert in db and use this code

```
$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        $sql = "select * from `mobiles` where `user_id`='$_SESSION[userid]' AND `id`='mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[con_id])' AND `activecode`='mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[regcode])' ";
```

but when i execute an error shown:

```
Catchable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /home/mobileab/public_html/index.php on line 116
```

why how can i use this in my code for sql injection?
thank you so

Comment: `id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[con_id])."'` and for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not concatenating correctly, functions are not executed in a string:

```
$sql = "select * from `mobiles` where `user_id`='$_SESSION[userid]'
          AND `id`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['con_id']) . "'
          AND `activecode`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['regcode']) . "'";
```

But I would recommend using a prepared statement instead.